# How to get Monthly data from previous year to the current year?

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I am trying to calculate the median of a measure, but I need previous year/month/weekday median data to be displayed on the current ones.

```
date        wday    admns   median  result
28/10/2016  Friday  7      37.5     0
21/10/2016  Friday  34     37.5     0
7/10/2016   Friday  41     37.5     0
14/10/2016  Friday  63     37.5     0

20/10/2017  Friday  23     49       37.5
27/10/2017  Friday  44     49       37.5
6/10/2017   Friday  54     49       37.5
13/10/2017  Friday  63     49       37.5
```

In the result column I need the previous year/month/day median to be displayed to he current year. For 2015 there is no data hence the result field is 0 for 2016 data.

I used this query to get the median

```
with a as (select dt,weekday,admns,extract(year from dt) year,to_char(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),'Month') month from med_drop)
select dt, weekday, admns , year,month,
       median(admns) over ( partition by year,weekday) export_table
from a;
```

test data

```
CREATE TABLE export_table
   (DT DATE, 
    WEEKDAY VARCHAR2(10), 
    ADMNS NUMBER
   );


Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('01/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Sunday',10);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('02/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Monday',12);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('03/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Tuesday',15);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('04/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Wednesday',52);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('05/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Thursday',23);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('06/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Friday',54);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('07/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Saturday',78);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('08/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Sunday',66);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('09/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Monday',5);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('10/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Tuesday',4);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('11/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Wednesday',78);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('12/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Thursday',99);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('13/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Friday',63);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('14/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Saturday',71);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('15/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Sunday',63);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('16/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Monday',89);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('17/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Tuesday',23);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('18/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Wednesday',45);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('19/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Thursday',87);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('20/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Friday',23);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('21/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Saturday',12);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('22/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Sunday',11);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('23/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Monday',63);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('24/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Tuesday',93);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('25/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Wednesday',23);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('26/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Thursday',88);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('27/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Friday',44);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('28/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Saturday',441);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('29/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Sunday',66);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('30/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Monday',23);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('31/OCT/2017 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Tuesday',16);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('01/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Saturday',55);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('02/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Sunday',67);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('03/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Monday',41);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('04/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Tuesday',85);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('05/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Wednesday',25);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('06/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Thursday',63);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('07/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Friday',41);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('08/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Saturday',87);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('09/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Sunday',46);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('10/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Monday',14);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('11/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Tuesday',74);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('12/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Wednesday',36);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('13/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Thursday',74);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('14/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Friday',63);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('15/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Saturday',14);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('16/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Sunday',96);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('17/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Monday',31);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('18/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Tuesday',41);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('19/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Wednesday',23);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('20/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Thursday',96);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('21/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Friday',34);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('22/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Saturday',74);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('23/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Sunday',63);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('24/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Monday',53);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('25/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Tuesday',76);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('26/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Wednesday',96);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('27/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Thursday',145);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('28/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Friday',7);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('29/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Saturday',8);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('30/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Sunday',4);
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,WEEKDAY,ADMNS) values (to_date('31/OCT/2016 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Monday',6);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`MEDIAN` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions086.htm#sthref1605):

> You can use `MEDIAN` as an analytic function. You can specify only the query_partition_clause in its `OVER` clause.

So, you cannot specify a *windowing* clause in the analytic query to filter it to only this/last year. Instead you can use correlated sub-queries:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d963/10)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE export_table(
  DT DATE, 
  WEEKDAY VARCHAR2(9) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CAST( TRIM( TO_CHAR( dt, 'Day' ) ) AS VARCHAR2(9) ) ) VIRTUAL, 
  ADMNS NUMBER
);

Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (DT,ADMNS)
SELECT DATE '2017-10-01',10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-02',12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-03',15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-04',52 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-05',23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-06',54 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-07',78 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-08',66 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-09',5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-10',4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-11',78 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-12',99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-13',63 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-14',71 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-15',63 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-16',89 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-17',23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-18',45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-19',87 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-20',23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-21',12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-22',11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-23',63 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-24',93 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-25',23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-26',88 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-27',44 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-28',441 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-29',66 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-30',23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-10-31',16 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-01',55 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-02',67 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-03',41 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-04',85 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-05',25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-06',63 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-07',41 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-08',87 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-09',46 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-10',14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-11',74 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-12',36 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-13',74 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-14',63 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-15',14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-16',96 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-17',31 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-18',41 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-19',23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-20',96 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-21',34 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-22',74 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-23',63 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-24',53 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-25',76 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-26',96 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-27',145 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-28',7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-29',8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-30',4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-10-31',6 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select dt,
       weekday,
       admns,
       ( SELECT MEDIAN( admns )
         FROM   export_table t
         WHERE  e.weekday = t.weekday
         AND    t.dt BETWEEN TRUNC( e.dt, 'MM' )
                         AND LAST_DAY( e.dt )
       ) AS this_years_median_for_month,
       ( SELECT MEDIAN( admns )
         FROM   export_table t
         WHERE  e.weekday = t.weekday
         AND    t.dt BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( e.dt, 'MM' ), -12 )
                         AND ADD_MONTHS( LAST_DAY( e.dt ), -12 )
       ) AS last_years_median_for_month
from   export_table e
where  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM dt ) = EXTRACT( MONTH FROM SYSDATE )
ORDER BY dt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d963/10/0)**:

```
|                   DT |   WEEKDAY | ADMNS | THIS_YEARS_MEDIAN_FOR_MONTH | LAST_YEARS_MEDIAN_FOR_MONTH |
|----------------------|-----------|-------|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|
| 2016-10-01T00:00:00Z |  Saturday |    55 |                          55 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-02T00:00:00Z |    Sunday |    67 |                          63 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-03T00:00:00Z |    Monday |    41 |                          31 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-04T00:00:00Z |   Tuesday |    85 |                          75 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-05T00:00:00Z | Wednesday |    25 |                        30.5 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-06T00:00:00Z |  Thursday |    63 |                          85 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-07T00:00:00Z |    Friday |    41 |                        37.5 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-08T00:00:00Z |  Saturday |    87 |                          55 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-09T00:00:00Z |    Sunday |    46 |                          63 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-10T00:00:00Z |    Monday |    14 |                          31 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-11T00:00:00Z |   Tuesday |    74 |                          75 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-12T00:00:00Z | Wednesday |    36 |                        30.5 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-13T00:00:00Z |  Thursday |    74 |                          85 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-14T00:00:00Z |    Friday |    63 |                        37.5 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-15T00:00:00Z |  Saturday |    14 |                          55 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-16T00:00:00Z |    Sunday |    96 |                          63 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-17T00:00:00Z |    Monday |    31 |                          31 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-18T00:00:00Z |   Tuesday |    41 |                          75 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-19T00:00:00Z | Wednesday |    23 |                        30.5 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-20T00:00:00Z |  Thursday |    96 |                          85 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-21T00:00:00Z |    Friday |    34 |                        37.5 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-22T00:00:00Z |  Saturday |    74 |                          55 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-23T00:00:00Z |    Sunday |    63 |                          63 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-24T00:00:00Z |    Monday |    53 |                          31 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-25T00:00:00Z |   Tuesday |    76 |                          75 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-26T00:00:00Z | Wednesday |    96 |                        30.5 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-27T00:00:00Z |  Thursday |   145 |                          85 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-28T00:00:00Z |    Friday |     7 |                        37.5 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-29T00:00:00Z |  Saturday |     8 |                          55 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-30T00:00:00Z |    Sunday |     4 |                          63 |                      (null) |
| 2016-10-31T00:00:00Z |    Monday |     6 |                          31 |                      (null) |
| 2017-10-01T00:00:00Z |    Sunday |    10 |                          63 |                          63 |
| 2017-10-02T00:00:00Z |    Monday |    12 |                          23 |                          31 |
| 2017-10-03T00:00:00Z |   Tuesday |    15 |                          16 |                          75 |
| 2017-10-04T00:00:00Z | Wednesday |    52 |                        48.5 |                        30.5 |
| 2017-10-05T00:00:00Z |  Thursday |    23 |                        87.5 |                          85 |
| 2017-10-06T00:00:00Z |    Friday |    54 |                          49 |                        37.5 |
| 2017-10-07T00:00:00Z |  Saturday |    78 |                        74.5 |                          55 |
| 2017-10-08T00:00:00Z |    Sunday |    66 |                          63 |                          63 |
| 2017-10-09T00:00:00Z |    Monday |     5 |                          23 |                          31 |
| 2017-10-10T00:00:00Z |   Tuesday |     4 |                          16 |                          75 |
| 2017-10-11T00:00:00Z | Wednesday |    78 |                        48.5 |                        30.5 |
| 2017-10-12T00:00:00Z |  Thursday |    99 |                        87.5 |                          85 |
| 2017-10-13T00:00:00Z |    Friday |    63 |                          49 |                        37.5 |
| 2017-10-14T00:00:00Z |  Saturday |    71 |                        74.5 |                          55 |
| 2017-10-15T00:00:00Z |    Sunday |    63 |                          63 |                          63 |
| 2017-10-16T00:00:00Z |    Monday |    89 |                          23 |                          31 |
| 2017-10-17T00:00:00Z |   Tuesday |    23 |                          16 |                          75 |
| 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z | Wednesday |    45 |                        48.5 |                        30.5 |
| 2017-10-19T00:00:00Z |  Thursday |    87 |                        87.5 |                          85 |
| 2017-10-20T00:00:00Z |    Friday |    23 |                          49 |                        37.5 |
| 2017-10-21T00:00:00Z |  Saturday |    12 |                        74.5 |                          55 |
| 2017-10-22T00:00:00Z |    Sunday |    11 |                          63 |                          63 |
| 2017-10-23T00:00:00Z |    Monday |    63 |                          23 |                          31 |
| 2017-10-24T00:00:00Z |   Tuesday |    93 |                          16 |                          75 |
| 2017-10-25T00:00:00Z | Wednesday |    23 |                        48.5 |                        30.5 |
| 2017-10-26T00:00:00Z |  Thursday |    88 |                        87.5 |                          85 |
| 2017-10-27T00:00:00Z |    Friday |    44 |                          49 |                        37.5 |
| 2017-10-28T00:00:00Z |  Saturday |   441 |                        74.5 |                          55 |
| 2017-10-29T00:00:00Z |    Sunday |    66 |                          63 |                          63 |
| 2017-10-30T00:00:00Z |    Monday |    23 |                          23 |                          31 |
| 2017-10-31T00:00:00Z |   Tuesday |    16 |                          16 |                          75 |
```

Comment: This works, I'll test this out and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this thing out, The real table is so large the query is running for long time. For each day it’s having hundreds of thousands records, and it also calculating sum (admns)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing two queries you would use the lag function, e.g.

```
with a as (select dt, weekday, admns, extract(year from dt) year, to_char(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),'Month') month from export_table),
     b as (select dt, weekday, admns, year, month, median(admns) over (partition by year, weekday) med from a)
select dt, weekday, admns, year, month, med, lag(med, extract(day from last_day(dt)) ) over (order by dt) med_prev
from b
order by dt;
```

This is just using the `extract(day from last_day(dt))` to get the offset, as there are only the two months in the sample data set.
For full year data you could use something like

```
lag(med, dt - add_months(dt,-12))
```

to get the offset.
Though this will probably use the previous Feb 28th median for Feb 29th, so you would need to handle this case differently if you didn't want that

This also assumes that the data set contains data for every day. If there are possible gaps, then these could be filled with the `a` cte slightly modified to fill in all the dates in the period of interest.

Comment: The OP appears to be comparing the median for each weekday of the current month against the same weekday of the same month in the previous year. If you use the value from the same day of the month in the previous year then it will be a different day of the week.

Comment: `LAG( med ) OVER ( PARTITION BY weekday, month ORDER BY year )` would possibly do it.